# How can I get the backround of my div in a fixed position?

Tags: image, html, positioning, background-image

I am wrighting a code for my new website and as you can scroll down on this div i need to fix the background:

```
    <div id="main" style="background-image:url('bg5.png'); background-repeat: repeat; background-        size: 924px; width:924px; height: 526px;  float: right; z-index:-1; overflow-y:scroll;">
    </div>
```

I need the answer as soon as possible, please help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To set the background image in a fixed position, you can use the following CSS:

```
background-attachment:fixed;
```

You can find some more information about the `background-attachment` property at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp